# WebClient downloads blank string for any url but only on Webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I've tested the code below locally using my MVC Web application, it works fine locally but always returns a blank string when testing on my live web server, I've tried different UserAgent values but with no success, I've also setup a windows forms app on the web server and tested the code but it downloads fine. I'm thinking it maybe some setting within my web.config file but I have very little understanding of how the web.config file works.

```
public class Web
    {
        private const string UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0";

        public static string DownloadPage(string url)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = UserAgent;

            return client.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't need to authenticate?

You don't need the UserAgent. 
Try it like this, this is how i got it working. You can now at least see the exception it'll throw.

```
    public string RequestUrl(string reqUrl)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            return client.DownloadString(reqUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "" + e;
        }
    }
```